# GROUP BY tags in tags array inside foreign collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking for away to group collection1 by tags that reside on collection2
the two collections needs to be joined (lookup) by 2 fields (field1, field2)

So far I came up with the following query:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "collection2",
            "let": { _field1: '$field1', _field2: '$field2' },
            "pipeline": [{
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": ["$field1", "$$_field1"] },
                            { "$eq": ["$field2", "$$_field2"] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            { "$project": { _id: 0, tags: 1 } },
            ],
            "as": "col2"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$col2" },
    { $group: { _id: "$col2.tags", count: { $sum: 1 } } }

    ]);
```

I got no result at all.

field1 and field2 are together unique in collection2 (having unique index)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct apart from the name of your variables in:

`{ _field1: '$field1', _field2: '$field2' },`

When you define such variables, they are called [user variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) and mongo has certain naming limitations on them that are different from "real" variables convention.

from the docs:

> User variable names must begin with a lowercase ascii letter [a-z] or a non-ascii character.

Meaning in your case the underscore is causing an error.

Comment: 10x mate, but changing the user variables to uv_field1 and uv_field2 made no difference

Comment: well on my local it works and previous to the change it threw an error, i think its time for you to check field names and schema field types to make sure a match is to be found. the syntax as i stated is correct.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have managed to solve it myself.

1. i have added a unique index on collection2 (filed1,field2)
2. added extra unwind to flat the tags array

my last query is as foolows:

```
 db.collection1.aggregate([
{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "collection2",
            "let": { field1: '$field1', field2: '$field2' },
            "pipeline": [{
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": ["$field1", "$$field1"] },
                            { "$eq": ["$field2", "$$field2"] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            { "$project": { _id: 0, tags: 1 } },
            ],
            "as": "col2"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$col2" },
    { "$unwind": "$col2.tags" },
    { $group: { _id: "$col2.tags", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
{ $sort: { count: -1 } },
    ]);
```